# Tensorflow not detecting GPU on Python 3.6.9 but working on Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tensorflow

I've created two virtual environments using `virtualenv venv2` for Python 2.7 and `virtualenv -p python3 venv3` for Python 3.6.9. After that, both virtual environments had downloaded Tensorflow via pip by using `pip install tensorflow`. I've read on [Tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) that GPU and CPU support is now included in the `tensorflow` package and there is no longer any need for installing `tensorflow-gpu` separately (although I did try that).

The problem is with my environment using Python 3:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

I've used this, as advised [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu), but the output is an empty array. On Python 2, I see `[PhysicalDevice(name=u'/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type=u'GPU')]`.

This is the output of `nvidia-smi`:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.102.04   Driver Version: 450.102.04   CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 20%   25C    P8     8W / 250W |      2MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

My current tensorflow version is 2.4.1. Any idea what's causing Tensorflow with Python 3 to not detect my GPU?

Comment: Is there more output than the empty array? If some CUDA components are missing tensorflow writes logs telling you that. Is this the case?

Comment: No, it's simply `[]` when running the command I've mentioned. I've tried several other commands I've found here and there and they print CPU info at most.

Comment: Maybe try using TensorFlow outside the venv?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't.

Comment: TensorFlow and GPU is generally a complete black box that is really hard to debug. Instead of trying to fix it I often choose now to just erase the linux and set it up new. A possible solution might be running the Python script with higher privileges. That worked sometimes, although I have no idea why